# ADD 1 Day more in From_UnixTime to Normal Date

Tags: mysql

I need to add 1 day extra in day, tried everything gives me n error

```
  Date_Format(From_UnixTime(attendance.date), '%Y %M %D') As date,
```

It shows me a date as 2020 August 10th.
I want to achieve an answer like this it should be 2020 August 11th

How do I do that?
What should be the query, already the dates in MySQL are saved in Unix dates. But dates showing 1 day behind

Answer (score 0):

First update the table so that it contains the correct dates:

```
UPDATE attendance 
SET date = UNIX_TIMESTAMP(FROM_UNIXTIME(date) + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Then, you can query the table with [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) only without the need of `DATE_FORMAT()`, because `FROM_UNIXTIME()` takes as 2nd argument the format that you want displayed:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date, '%Y %M %D') AS date
FROM attendance;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9997eccbcdadaeaff94ed48cf3168f83).

Comment: Thanks a ton sir for your reply.. the problem is i need to fetch the reports daily.
and every time more records will be added.
 if i update the attendance table now,
 then new records will again be 1 day behind, 
then if i update then extra day will be added to already added date.

Comment: @SwayamiddhiMBACOLLEGEThane why do you insert wrong data?